# MERN Stack App Deployment Issue! ||| Seems like there shouldn't be an errors

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, deployment, mern

**I've deployed my MERN stack app on Heroku successfully (it's alright in Heroku's logs)** *but when following the link where it is deployed I only see "Heroku | Welcome to your new app! Refer to the documentation if you need help deploying.". And in devtools console I see:

"https://women-wear-app.herokuapp.com/ 502 (Bad Gateway)
GET https://women-wear-app.herokuapp.com/favicon.ico 502 (Bad Gateway)"
Please help me, I'll give a link to my Github repos if needed*

---

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that I didn't fully deploy my app and it just wasn't completely deployed. :) solved! WOOHOO